# Spark SQL performance difference in spark-sql vs spark-shell REPL

Tags: apache-spark

Spark newb question: I'm making exactly the same Spark SQL query in `spark-sql` and in `spark-shell`.  The `spark-shell` version takes about 10 seconds, while the `spark-sql` version takes about 20.

The spark-sql REPL gets the query directly:

```
spark-sql> SELECT .... FROM .... LIMIT 20
```

The spark-shell REPL commands are like this:

```
scala> val df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT ... FROM ... LIMIT 20 ") 
scala> df.show()
```

In both cases, it's exactly the same query.  Also, the query returns only a few rows because of the explicit `LIMIT 20`.

What's different about how the same query is executed from the different CLIs?

I'm running on Hortonworks sandbox VM (Linux CentOS) if that helps.

Comment: For the spark-shell version, is it 10 seconds for just the df.show() call or 10 seconds for both the sqlContext.sql call and the df.show call? DataFrame initialization isn't free (depending on the datasource) and so even before an action such as collect/show is called, you could spend a non-trivial time initializing. The spark-sql call is likely performing both steps as the spark-shell call so it's important to be comparing apples to apples.

Comment: the DataFrame initialization is almost instantaneous - the time is all in `df.show`.

Comment: It is possible that spark is deferring initialization. (Tables not loaded until accessed when the query is executed at  show)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more about two parts,

1. First, it could be related the order. If you run the spark-sql first spark will be able to build the explain plan from scratch. But if you run the same query again. It could take less than the first one either from shell or sql because the explain plan will be easy to be retrieved
2. Second, it could be related to the spark-sql conversion to the ordering the resources. It happened multiple times. Spark-shell get the resources and start the process faster than spark-sql. You can check this from the UI or from `top` you will find the actual start for the spark-shell is faster than spark-sql.